# Javascript Looping through functions to make spans hidden and visible

Tags: javascript, html, loops, styles

An assignment I have is to make a FAQ page for a website that displays an answer when you click on a question and also only allows one question to be visible at a time. I did this so far:

```
<li button onclick="answerOne();">question</li>
<span id="FAQA1" style="visibility: hidden; color: red;">answer</span>
<li button onclick="answerTwo();">question</li>
<span id="FAQA2" style="visibility: hidden; color: red;">answer</span>
<li button onclick="answerThree();">question</li>
<span id="FAQA3" style="visibility: hidden; color: red;">answer</span>
```

And my Javascript looks like this:

```
function answerOne() {
        document.getElementById("FAQA1").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("FAQA2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("FAQA3").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    function answerTwo() {
        document.getElementById("FAQA1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("FAQA2").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("FAQA3").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    function answerThree() {
        document.getElementById("FAQA1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("FAQA2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("FAQA3").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
```

Now this is all well and good but if the page ever gets bigger, you'd have to change every single function. I know there must be a better way to be able to achieve the same result but I seem to have hit a wall. If anyone knows a way to do this, can you point me in the right direction or to a source where I can find it? Many thanks.

Comment: You have numbers, and you can toggle classes. Seems fairly straight-forward... What's the specific conceptual hurdle that's causing a problem? Seems like you just need an index and done string concatenation (that's the easiest first step, anyway).

Comment: The markup is invalid. What is with the `button` attribute for the `<li>` elements? O.o You may also have a look at a [definition list (`<dl>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var current = false;

function makeActive( key ) {

    if( current !== false ) {

        document.getElementById( "FAQ" + current ).style.visibility = "hidden";

    }

    document.getElementById( "FAQ" + key ).style.visibility = "visible";

    current = key;

}
```

calling `makeActive( "A1" );` would make FAQ item "A1" be visible and the previously active one become invisible

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways you can do this. Here's one that doesn't involve so many functions.

Set up your HTML like this:

```
<li onclick="showAnswer('FAQA1')">question</li>
<span id="FAQA1" class="answer" style="visibility: hidden; color: red;">answer</span>
<li onclick="showAnswer('FAQA2')">question</li>
<span id="FAQA2" class="answer" style="visibility: hidden; color: red;">answer</span>
<li onclick="showAnswer('FAQA3')">question</li>
<span id="FAQA3" class="answer" style="visibility: hidden; color: red;">answer</span>
```

Notice that all the `li` elements use the same function and simply pass a string to it. The answer `spans` all have the same class and a unique `id`.

Then the Javascript:

```
function showAnswer(ele) {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.answer'), function(el) {
      el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });
    document.getElementById(ele).style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

So here, there's a `forEach` loop on all the elements with class `answer` (the answer spans). This loops through all the answers and hides them. Then, the last line selects the element with a particular id (that we've passed into the function as a string from the onclick) and sets that answer visible.

A fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dsmw0abe/2/

Also, just FYI, keep in mind that `visibility` is different from `display`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that allows you to have an unlimited number of questions. By giving every answer `span` the same class, you do not have to explicitly define each one in your code.

*Because your answers start at 1, I am starting the loop at 1 instead of 0.*

Example:

```
window.answerQuestion = function answerQuestion(id) {
  var questionEls = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");

  for (var x = 1; x <= questionEls.length; x++) {
    var question = questionEls[x-1];

    if (x === id) {
      question.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
      question.style.visibility = ' hidden';
    }
  }

};
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/j3k89o5a/

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to to start w/ all answers hidden then listen for an event within the div at which time you can capture which item was clicked and toggle visibility of nearest following answer. If it is clicked again, it will toggle that answer closed. This allows the user to open each question as they see fit and prevents the page from jumping around - i.e. closing previous answer when a new question is clicked.

*For Example*

**HTML**

```
<div class="faq">
  <h1>First Question</h1>
  <p>Answer to the question</p>
  <h1>Second Question</h1>
  <p>Answer to the question</p>
  <h1>Third Question</h1>
  <p>Answer to the question</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.faq {
  display: none
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery** (could be done w/ vanilla js, if needed)

```
$(function() {
  $('.faq h1').click(function() {
    $(this).next('p').slideToggle(400);
  });
});
```

Comment: My fault, I meant h1s or any headline elements. You could do a list with sublist items within if you wanted.